# how to make parent function not work when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```js
const App = () => {
  return <div onClick={()=>{console.log('world')}}>
    <button type='button' onClick={()=>{console.log('hello')}}>Click me!</button>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

when pressing button must working button function, not div function

Answer (score 2):

### **Add [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to your button onClick:**

```js
const App = () => (
  <div
    onClick={() => {
      console.log('world');
    }}
  >
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={(event) => {
        console.log('hello');
        event.stopPropagation();   // <-- ADD THIS
      }}
    >
      Click me!
    </button>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```